WebkitWebView Permission denied
I'm writing a gtk4 application in C on Linux kubuntu. The main window uses WebkitWebView. Everything goes fine until the method webkit_web_view_load_uri(browser, "https://youtube.com") is called;
When calling this method, the error bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied occurs. If I run the application under sudo everything works.
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkitgtk-6.0/webkit/webkit.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    WebKitWebView *browser;
  
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Заголовок");

    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default();
    GListModel *list = gdk_display_get_monitors( display );
    g_object_unref (display);
    guint size = g_list_model_get_n_items( list );
    int monitor_width = 0, monitor_height = 0, window_x = 0, window_y = 0;

    GdkMonitor *biggest_monitor = NULL;
    for( guint i=0; i<size; i++ )
    {
        GdkMonitor *temp_monitor = GDK_MONITOR( g_list_model_get_item( list, i ));
        GdkRectangle rect;
        gdk_monitor_get_geometry( temp_monitor, &rect );
        if( monitor_width < rect.width )
        {
            monitor_width = rect.width;
            monitor_height = rect.height;
            window_x = rect.x;
            window_y = rect.y;
            biggest_monitor = temp_monitor;
        }
      g_object_unref (temp_monitor);
    }
  g_object_unref (biggest_monitor);

  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), monitor_width, monitor_height);
 
  box=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,10);  
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), box);

  browser = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW( webkit_web_view_new());
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(browser),monitor_width,monitor_height);
  gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box),GTK_WIDGET(browser));

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  WebKitSettings *settings= webkit_web_view_get_settings(browser);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_media(settings, 1);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_webaudio(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_media_stream(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_media_playback_allows_inline(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_media_capabilities(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_enable_javascript(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_allow_universal_access_from_file_urls(settings,1);
  webkit_settings_set_media_playback_requires_user_gesture(settings,1);
  
  webkit_web_view_load_uri(browser, "https://youtube.com");

  gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(browser));

Why does webkitwebview needs to get root rights?

is that a gtk issue or a bubblewrap message ( the latter methinks ). what environment is this running under (docket/https://kubernetes/....)
